# How to solve $\sec^4(x)=\tan^4(x)+3\tan(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**Background**

I was trying to solve this purely trigonometric equation:

$$\sec(x)^4=\tan(x)^4+3\tan(x)$$

I performed my usual tactic,which is to rewrite everything in terms of sin and cos, and solve the resultant equation. (Works 100% of the time,70% of the time) and got:

$$1=\sin(x)^4+3\sin(x)\cos(x)^3$$

Which I could not solve, although if anybody CAN solve it I would love to hear how. So I input the original equation into a computer algebra system and it told me that it is an equivalent problem to the solution of this equation:

$$2\sec(x)^2=3\tan(x)+1$$

Now this was solvable with the same approach that failed on the original equation. I just converted it into a quartic polynomial problem at the end, after rewriting it in terms of sin and cos.

But a number of questions arose, the answers to which would greatly help my ability to solve trig equations, but for the purpose of this site I think i'll split them up into multiple posts each with a very precise focus, so that they will be more useful to other users.

Question: How do I know if a given trigonometric equation can be simplified?
(of course im primarily concerned about non obvious cases)

and by

> simplified

I think the example I gave is a good one for what I mean by simplified. Two things happened:

(1) The number of terms in the equation that contained trigonometric functions was reduced. it went from 3 in the original to only 2 in the computer algebra system's output

(2) The order (natural power) of any trig terms in the equations was reduced.

**How do I know if it is possible to accomplish one or both of these goals, given a purely trigonometric equation?**
(note: im not asking for a general procedure to do so, just a method of determining if this can be done given a purely trigonometric equation. I will ask other questions that arose from this problem later. )

Comment: Why do you stick to sin and cos rather than using the identity $\sec^2 x = \tan^2 x + 1$ from the outset? You immediately get a *quadratic* in $\tan x$.

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't know until you try.

Comment: Agreeing with what @AdamRubinson says, I think this is why math is "difficult". You just need to put in the practice.

Comment: It's impossible in the general case as that's equivalent to solving the halting problem.

Answer (score 6):

> $$1=\sin(x)^4+3\sin(x)\cos(x)^3$$

Start from here,

$$\begin{align}
1&=\sin^4(x)+3\sin(x)\cos^3(x)\\
\\
1-\sin^4(x)&=3\sin(x)\cos^3(x)\\
\\
(1+\sin^2(x))\cos^2(x)&=3\sin(x)\cos^3(x)\\
\\
&\Rightarrow \cos(x)=0\tag{1}\\
\\
&\text{or}\\
\\
1+\sin^2(x)&=3\sin(x)\cos(x)\\
\\
\cos^2(x)+2\sin^2(x)&=3\sin(x)\cos(x)\\
\\
1+2\tan^2(x)&=3\tan(x)\\
\\
(\tan(x)-1)(2\tan(x)-1)&=0\\
\\
&\Rightarrow \tan(x)=1 ~~\text{or} ~~\tan(x)=\frac{1}2\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

From (1), (2) we get:

$$x=\frac{\pi}2+n\pi, ~\frac{\pi}4+n\pi,~ \arctan\left(\frac{1}2\right)+n\pi, n\in\mathbb{Z}$$